# What's up with Wordpress?

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up, network-sites

[wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) and [Wordpress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com) confusion is a problem. With over 137,000 questions tagged over here and 85,000 questions over at the SE site, new users probably have a lot of confusion and most likely misjudge where the question should go. I propose we cleanup the tag. However, this isn't a lasting solution, so I also think we should have a selection box to allow automatic migration (before the question is asked) to the other Wordpress if they deem necessary. Also, I would love to see a hammer relating to this, perhaps it requires dupe hammer here and 5-10K there. I think we may have thousands of misplaced questions on our hands, and we need to look at the managing of sites/tags that may be confused in the future.

**TL;DR:** Cleanup [wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) and think about how to handle future confusion.

Comment: So you want to clean it up - how?  why?  Do we have a lot of off-topic Wordpress questions that would be on-topic good questions for Wordpress.SE?  Keep in mind the programming question about Wordpess are still on-topic here even though they might also be on-topic on Wordpress.SE as well

Comment: @psubsee2003 I believe that the even the [top voted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303372/create-a-folder-if-it-doesnt-already-exist) would probably be a better fit for WordPress.SE, and I know that it isn't the only one that would be better. Also, we need to make it clear where each question goes. On-topic here should be off-topic there, off-topic there should be on-topic here. This makes it easier to catalog the questions and remove duplicates.

Comment: "off-topic here should be on-topic there" and visa versa... that is not how the site works.  Questions can be on-topic on multiple sites.  A couple of items to help your proposal here... Old questions can't be migrated even if you think they would be "better".  The limit is 6 months.  Moderators cannot override this restriction.  Also "better fit" is not a justifiable reason to migrate. It has to be off-topic on the original site first.

Comment: @psubsee2003 didn't think about 6 months, but we can still cv them. The top voted question was an example to show how many questions would be 100% without a doubt off-topic. We need to make it more clear cut what is on-topic and off-topic, because we essentially are a knowledge database, and if we can't be searched, then we just wasted our time.

Comment: Well, it's PHP to start with:(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't illustrate any specific questions that are the source of confusion so it is hard to weigh in on any specific examples.  However, to start I am going to offer a couple of thoughts

1. There are historical questions that were asked long before Wordpress.SE was site, such as the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303372/create-a-folder-if-it-doesnt-already-exist) in your comments.
2. Old questions can't be migrated.  More specifically questions that are older than 6 months cannot be migrated even by moderators (in extremely exceptional circumstances they can be by SO employees, but that is not likely to happen here)

But irrespective of the above points **questions can be on-topic on multiple sites**.  Just because it is on-topic on Site A doesn't automatically make it off-topic on Site B.  So while Wordpress.SE accepts programming questions about Wordpress, they are still on topic on SO, so both sites are viable locations to ask questions, even if you think it would be better asked on a different site.

If it is a non-programming question about Wordpress asked on SO, then it should be close voted.  But there is no direct migration path to WordPress.  There are a handful of sites that the users can chose to migrate questions too, and of the  limited number of options available, Wordpress is not among them.  If the question is of high quality and is a good question for Wordpress.SE, you can use a custom flag to get a moderator to move it (assuming it is newer than 6 months old).

[image: mirgration target locations]

There is no automatic migration to any site and no "dupe hammer migrations" either.  You have to resort to a normal migration flag if it is on the list, or a custom moderator flag.

If you are seeing a significant number of off-topic questions on a particular tag that are on-topic elsewhere, not just those you think would be better suited for a different site, then bring specific examples to the table and see how the community feels.